# Change Azure DevOps Parent Work Item status when all linked children work items meet certain condition?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I see there are plenty of options for creating custom rules in Azure DevOps, but I don't see one (or perhaps I'm not interpreting it correctly), that handles this scenario.

I have an Epic.
That Epic has a state of "In Progress".

That Epic has 10 user stories as linked child items. Each Story has a state as well.

Can I create a rule that when all 10 of those stories stages reach "Done", then the parent Epic will automatically change state to "Done"?

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of this time, however, automate state transitions of parent work items by Azure DevOps process rules is not supported.

But you can add a web hook and use the code and configuration provided in the [Automate State Transitions](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-boards-automate-state-transitions) GitHub project.

Click [this link](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-boards-automate-state-transitions#setup) for detailed information about setting up the project.

Comment: hey @Jane Ma-MSFT, you may want to update your answer as there's now this automation rule for exactly this state transition available. You can choose to set a parent active when at least one child is set to a state of state category active and you can choose to either resolve or complete parents when all children completed